# Swift - Print what the current week of the year is

Tags: swift, date, week-number

I need a way of printing the number of weeks so far this year. 

I have managed to print the number of days and also the number of months (see the code below). 

But cannot figure out how to do the same for the total number of weeks.

Total days so far this year:

```
let dateDay = Date()
                        let dateFormatterDay = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatterDay.dateFormat = "DD"
                        let dateByDay = dateFormatterDay.string(from: dateDay)
                        print(dateByDay)
```

Total months so far this year:

```
 let dateMonth = Date()
                        let dateFormatterMonth = DateFormatter()
                        dateFormatterMonth.dateFormat = "MM"
                        let dateByMonth = dateFormatterMonth.string(from: dateMonth)
                        print(dateByMonth)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code snippet. It is written in **Swift 4 and Swift 5**.

```
let currentDate = Date() 
print(currentDate.dayOfYear)   // Day of Year
print(currentDate.weekOfYear)  // Week of Year
print(currentDate.monthOfYear) // Month of Year
```

This will print the total days, weeks & months of the year respectively.

```
extension Date {
    public var dayOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
    public var weekOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .weekOfYear, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
    public var monthOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .month, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! I had some previous tryouts with "calendar.component" but never managed to get it working. This was perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Swift123 Most Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for today's date:

```
Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .weekOfYear, in: .year, for: Date())!
```

Likewise, you could use it for the day of the year:

```
Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
```

Or the current month:

```
Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .month, in: .year, for: self)!
```

You could also define these as extensions on `Date`:

```
extension Date {
    public var dayOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
    public var weekOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .weekOfYear, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
    public var monthOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.ordinality(of: .month, in: .year, for: self)!
    }
}

let nowDate = Date() //"Sep 3, 2018 at 10:54 AM"
nowDate.dayOfYear    //246
nowDate.weekOfYear   //36
nowDate.monthOfYear  //9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date{
    var weekOfYear: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.weekOfYear,  from: self)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
print("WeakOfYear :: ", Date().weekOfYear)
```